# added spark-xml_2.11 file into databricks library and creating the dataframes

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I has added the spark-xml_2.11 into my databricks library option as a marven coordinate

groupId: com.databricks
artifactId: spark-xml_2.11
version: 0.4.1

and trying to load the data to DF like below

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='catalog').load('smaple.xml')
```

and getting the below error.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Comment: Have you attached it to your cluster as well?

Comment: Yes. I was attached it

Comment: Try detach-reattach the notebook to the cluster if you've already executed some code so that the classpath gets refreshed with the new library

Comment: Again try to run it's saying like java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html. Even I tried to restart the cluster and detached notebook before I restart the cluster